# restart cron service script with non root user aix

Tags: cron, aix

I need to make a batch that restart cron service on aix system,but it must be done with non root user??
I need to do so because in aix you must restart cron service when modifying crontab file, in order to accepts the new changes..

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`crontab` command](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/topic/com.ibm.aix.cmds/doc/aixcmds1/crontab.htm) to submit the updated cron file.  It will signal crond to reload/reset.

Comment: thanks a lot but the the answer to my question is :                                         to user "crontab fully_Qualified_FileName"  where  fully_Qualified_FileName = absolute path for my crontab file